# Multiple ON WHERE SQL , cant get it to work

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to work out a way to only show contact details based on DPA.value , so contacts can be xcluded from the output list based on the DPA value , excluding the contact if dpa value equals 5. Exclude email address if DPA value =3 or 4. Exclude phone if value = 2 or 4

Exclude contact if the DB.OrganisationPersonnel.EmployedToDate) Is Null 
    This code does not seem to be working , any help would be much appreciated.

```
    SELECT
        DB.OrganisationPersonnel.OrganisationID
      , DB.OrganisationPersonnel.PersonnelID AS [if not ProductPAID =5]
      , DB.Title.Name
      , DB.Person.FirstName
      , DB.Person.MiddleName
      , DB.Person.LastName
      , DB.OrganisationPersonnel.ActualJobTitle
      , DB.Phone.Number AS [if ProductPAID <3]
      , DB.Email.Email AS [if ProductPAID =2 or 5]
      , DB.Person.ProductDPAID
      , DB.ProductDPA.Name
    FROM
       (((DB.OrganisationPersonnel 
    INNER JOIN
       (DB.Person 
    INNER JOIN
       DB.Title 
    ON
       DB.Person.TitleID = DB.Title.ID) 
    ON
       DB.OrganisationPersonnel.PersonnelID = DB.Person.ID) 
    LEFT JOIN
       DB.Phone 
    ON
       DB.OrganisationPersonnel.PhoneID = DB.Phone.ID) 

    LEFT JOIN
       DB.Email 
    ON
       DB.OrganisationPersonnel.EmailID = DB.Email.ID)  


    INNER JOIN
       DB.ProductDPA 
    ON
       DB.Person.ProductDPAID = DB.ProductDPA.ID
    WHERE
       (((DB.OrganisationPersonnel.EmployedToDate) Is Null))
    ORDER BY
       DB.OrganisationPersonnel.OrganisationID;
```

I tried to add additional ON WHERE but cant work out how to without errors. Any help would be much appreciated as I am quite new to SQL.

Comment: There's only a single WHERE, simply `AND`/`OR` additional conditions to it.

Comment: Post your expected output along with some sample dataset to produce it

Comment: Learn to use table alias.  The repeating long table names are really annoying.  So do all the those brackets.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need any brackets in your `FROM` clause. Just remove them. The database engine query optimizer will do the joins in the best possible order for you.

And next, you are getting syntax errors on your `ON` context. You should combine several matches by using `AND` expression, because it is just a boolean expressions there. Instead of writing

```
ON
   DB.Person.TitleID = DB.Title.ID) 
ON
   DB.OrganisationPersonnel.PersonnelID = DB.Person.ID)
```

do write

```
ON DB.Person.TitleID = DB.Title.ID
   AND DB.OrganisationPersonnel.PersonnelID = DB.Person.ID
```

Comment: Thankyou , how do I write the if statements based on the code ProductDPA. I have 3 if statements required 1. if it equal 5 then dont add that contact detail. If it is 2 or 4 then dont add the email , if it is 3 or 4 dont add the phone

Comment: The `ON` are correct as long as the brackets are not removed, it's using the "other* (hardly known) syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Your joins are fine (although most people prefer the syntax variation where JOIN is followed directly by ON). But you should start using *aliases* to simplify writing & reading of the source code:

```
SELECT
    op.OrganisationID
  , t.Name
  , p.FirstName
...
FROM
   (((DB.OrganisationPersonnel AS op
INNER JOIN
   (DB.Person AS p
INNER JOIN
   DB.Title AS t
ON
   p.TitleID = t.ID) 
ON
   op.PersonnelID = p.ID) 
...
```

`IF` is implemented in Standard SQL using `CASE`:

```
SELECT
    op.OrganisationID
  , CASE WHEN ProductPAID <> 5 THEN op.PersonnelID END AS PersonnelID
  , DB.Title.Name
... 
  , CASE WHEN ProductPAID <3 THEN p.Number END AS PhoneNumber
  , CASE WHEN ProductPAID IN (2, 5) THEN e.Email END AS email
```

This will return NULL for non-matchng data, but there's an optional `ELSE` to override it with a default.

Comment: I am getting this error when I add the above Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.

Comment: @JohnD: You probably put the CASEs in the wrong place, should be *instead* of the column name in the SELECT list (and don't forget to add a comma after END.

Comment: Thanks how to I add it please , I have tried various places but still errors , i tried to add it  within this section of code                   
    SELECT 
    dbo.OrganisationPersonnel.OrganisationID
  , null AS PersonnelID -- PersonnelID is null if ProductDPA =5
  , dbo.Title.Name
  , dbo.Person.FirstName
  , dbo.Person.MiddleName
  , dbo.Person.LastName
  , dbo.OrganisationPersonnel.ActualJobTitle
  , dbo.Phone.Number 
  , dbo.Email.Email 
  , dbo.Person.ProductDPAID
  , dbo.ProductDPA.Name
FROM

Comment: @JohnD: Modified my answer to show the exact position of the CASEs.

Answer (score 0):

You can write Simple query but long Like This

```
--[PersonnelID is null if ProductDPA =5]
SELECT 
    dbo.OrganisationPersonnel.OrganisationID
  , null AS PersonnelID -- PersonnelID is null if ProductDPA =5
  , dbo.Title.Name
  , dbo.Person.FirstName
  , dbo.Person.MiddleName
  , dbo.Person.LastName
  , dbo.OrganisationPersonnel.ActualJobTitle
  , dbo.Phone.Number 
  , dbo.Email.Email 
  , dbo.Person.ProductDPAID
  , dbo.ProductDPA.Name
FROM
   dbo.OrganisationPersonnel  
   INNER JOIN dbo.Person ON dbo.OrganisationPersonnel.PersonnelID = dbo.Person.ID
   INNER JOIN dbo.Title ON dbo.Person.TitleID = dbo.Title.ID
   LEFT JOIN  dbo.Phone ON dbo.OrganisationPersonnel.PhoneID = dbo.Phone.ID
   LEFT JOIN  dbo.Email ON dbo.OrganisationPersonnel.EmailID = dbo.Email.ID
   INNER JOIN dbo.ProductDPA  ON dbo.Person.ProductDPAID = dbo.ProductDPA.ID
WHERE dbo.Person.ProductDPAID = 5  --All ProductDPA =5 & All EmployedToDate Is Null
or dbo.OrganisationPersonnel.EmployedToDate Is Null 
union all  
--Phone Number is null if ProductDPA = 2  
SELECT
    dbo.OrganisationPersonnel.OrganisationID
  , OrganisationPersonnel.PersonnelID 
  , dbo.Title.Name
  , dbo.Person.FirstName
  , dbo.Person.MiddleName
  , dbo.Person.LastName
  , dbo.OrganisationPersonnel.ActualJobTitle
  , null as Number  --Phone Number is null if ProductDPA = 2  
  , dbo.Email.Email 
  , dbo.Person.ProductDPAID
  , dbo.ProductDPA.Name
FROM
   dbo.OrganisationPersonnel  
   INNER JOIN dbo.Person ON dbo.OrganisationPersonnel.PersonnelID = dbo.Person.ID
   INNER JOIN dbo.Title ON dbo.Person.TitleID = dbo.Title.ID
   LEFT JOIN  dbo.Phone ON dbo.OrganisationPersonnel.PhoneID = dbo.Phone.ID
   LEFT JOIN  dbo.Email ON dbo.OrganisationPersonnel.EmailID = dbo.Email.ID
   INNER JOIN dbo.ProductDPA  ON dbo.Person.ProductDPAID = dbo.ProductDPA.ID
WHERE ProductDPAID in (2)  --Phone Number is null if ProductDPA = 2 
union all
--Email is null if ProductDPA =3
SELECT
    dbo.OrganisationPersonnel.OrganisationID
  , OrganisationPersonnel.PersonnelID  
  , dbo.Title.Name
  , dbo.Person.FirstName
  , dbo.Person.MiddleName
  , dbo.Person.LastName
  , dbo.OrganisationPersonnel.ActualJobTitle
  , dbo.Phone.Number   
  , null AS Email --Email is null if ProductDPA =3 
  , dbo.Person.ProductDPAID
  , dbo.ProductDPA.Name
FROM
   dbo.OrganisationPersonnel  
   INNER JOIN dbo.Person ON dbo.OrganisationPersonnel.PersonnelID = dbo.Person.ID
   INNER JOIN dbo.Title ON dbo.Person.TitleID = dbo.Title.ID
   LEFT JOIN  dbo.Phone ON dbo.OrganisationPersonnel.PhoneID = dbo.Phone.ID
   LEFT JOIN  dbo.Email ON dbo.OrganisationPersonnel.EmailID = dbo.Email.ID
   INNER JOIN dbo.ProductDPA  ON dbo.Person.ProductDPAID = dbo.ProductDPA.ID
WHERE ProductDPAID in (3)  --Email is null if ProductDPA =3 
union all
--Phone Number and Email is null if ProductDPA = 4
SELECT
    dbo.OrganisationPersonnel.OrganisationID
  , OrganisationPersonnel.PersonnelID  
  , dbo.Title.Name
  , dbo.Person.FirstName
  , dbo.Person.MiddleName
  , dbo.Person.LastName
  , dbo.OrganisationPersonnel.ActualJobTitle
  , null as Number     
  , null AS Email  
  , dbo.Person.ProductDPAID
  , dbo.ProductDPA.Name
FROM
   dbo.OrganisationPersonnel  
   INNER JOIN dbo.Person ON dbo.OrganisationPersonnel.PersonnelID = dbo.Person.ID
   INNER JOIN dbo.Title ON dbo.Person.TitleID = dbo.Title.ID
   LEFT JOIN  dbo.Phone ON dbo.OrganisationPersonnel.PhoneID = dbo.Phone.ID
   LEFT JOIN  dbo.Email ON dbo.OrganisationPersonnel.EmailID = dbo.Email.ID
   INNER JOIN dbo.ProductDPA  ON dbo.Person.ProductDPAID = dbo.ProductDPA.ID
WHERE ProductDPAID in (4)  --Email is null if ProductDPA = 4 
ORDER BY
   dbo.OrganisationPersonnel.OrganisationID;
```

and you must write join as in example

Comment: Thanks for taking time to write the script , the script ran without errors , though it did not change the phone or email or hide contact based on the ProductPAID ID

Comment: the idea is to replace the phone or email or contact by null  according to  the conditions which written in each where  clause. also you can remove  the repeated rows if you used union instead of union allو Good luck @JohnD

Answer (score 0):

Try the query below.

```
SELECT op.OrganisationID
    , (CASE WHEN ProductPAID = 5 THEN op.PersonnelID ELSE NULL END) AS [if not ProductPAID =5]
    , t.Name
    , p.FirstName
    , p.MiddleName
    , p.LastName
    , op.ActualJobTitle
    , (CASE WHEN ProductPAID < 3 THEN ph.Number ELSE NULL END) AS [if ProductPAID <3]
    , (CASE WHEN ProductPAID = 2 OR ProductPAID = 5 THEN e.Email ELSE NULL END) AS [if ProductPAID =2 or 5]
    , p.ProductDPAID
    , dpa.Name
FROM DB.OrganisationPersonnel op
JOIN DB.Person p ON op.PersonnelID = p.ID
JOIN DB.Title t ON p.TitleID = t.ID
JOIN DB.ProductDPA dpa ON p.ProductDPAID = dpa.ID
LEFT JOIN DB.Email e ON op.EmailID = e.ID
LEFT JOIN DB.Phone ph ON op.PhoneID = op.PhoneID
WHERE op.EmployedToDate IS NULL
ORDER BY op.OrganisationID;
```

Comment: Thanks that is nearly there , though what I need is for DPA = 5 or employed to date is not null , then no contact details are added , so no id , title , first name , middle name , last name , phone , email , DPA code etc. Any help to resolve that would be a great help

Comment: @JohnD Please provide sample input and expected output for all scenarios.  Otherwise it's hard to interpret what you mean.

Comment: I have a list of contacts that are linked by OrganisationID , then OrganisationPersonnelID then Person , Title , FirstName , MiddleName , LastName , Phone , Email , DPAID   . If the employedto is not null , which means if there is no end date added or if DPA =5 which means exclude the contact , then all the contact details for that personnel id are not added